# Samsung np530u3c booting issue after installing Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, ultrabook

I've read everything that works for everyone else, but none of it worked for me because my situation is a little different.

I get that many people have problems installing Windows 7 (after erasing the OEM Windows) from USB stick. But I got that part solved by using my other PC to install Windows 7 Pro fresh for the new SSD I bought (240 GB Kingston).

After that, I removed the previous HDD from my Samsung np530u3c laptop and insert the new SSD with that Windows installed on it. When I hit the power button, the screen just froze. I waited for it for awhile, maybe for a good few minutes. It starts to load Windows, but it gets stuck on the loading screen quite a bit. Then it will show an error page saying "Disk read error occurred, please Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart"

Does anyone know what is going on?

Note: the SSD is new. I have it run on my other PC to install Windows 7 Pro and there was no problem.

Comment: You can't usually install Windows on one computer and then transfer the drive to another computer like that. Windows keeps track of the type of hardware on which it was installed. That may not have anything to do with your error message, but it's still possible that it will cause other problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to transfer old Hard drive to new computer without reformating](https://superuser.com/questions/1266192/how-to-transfer-old-hard-drive-to-new-computer-without-reformating)

Comment: Okay, after spending more time on it after this post by asking my IT friend, he said that I cant do the transfer of windows like that too.

I have actually identified the problem. It is because such model of laptop has the iSSD embedded into the system and it can't be erased. Therefore, I couldnt create empty disks environment to allow windows installation.

I have not found anyway to delete the data in that iSSD yet. After speaking to Samsung IT support, she told me the only way is to send my laptop to Samsung service center to allow them to do installation for me. 

Oh well..

Comment: installing Windows on a computer and then removing driver/hardware configuration/licensing information can be done, and is usually done in the past by admins who want to flash an OS image to multiple PCs, but it's quite tricky. You need to read about [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation), [Can You Move a Windows Installation to Another Computer?](https://www.howtogeek.com/239815/why-cant-you-move-a-windows-installation-to-another-computer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the operating system installed on a PC, the drivers in this operating system are related to this PC, and may not be suitable for other PCs or laptops, unless the hardware configuration information between the PCs is exactly the same, then the operating system installed on this PC can be taken directly to other PCs, or the hardware configuration information between the laptops is exactly the same, then the operating system installed on this laptop can be taken directly to other laptops.

According to your description, the original of this laptop is HDD+SSD, and its SSD is integrated on the motherboard.

If the original operating system of the laptop is installed on the original SSD, when we remove the previous HDD from the laptop and insert the new SSD with that Windows installed on it, then the current system is booted from the original SSD (if we do not set the laptop to boot from the new SSD).

If the original system is installed on the HDD, when we remove the previous HDD from the laptop and insert the new SSD with  Windows installed on it, the current operating system cannot be booted, the operating system installed on the PC cannot be booted on this laptop(if we set the laptop to boot from the new SSD).  As mentioned above, because the driver is not compatible.

We can try the following two ways to reinstall operating system of laptop on new SSD:

**Method 1**

1. First install a new SSD with no operating system to the laptop.
2. Then install the operating system to this SSD from the USB flash drive.
3. We need to set the laptop to boot from the new SSD.
4. View if we can boot from the new SSD successfully.

**Method 2**

We can try to change the SSD from the PC to the laptop during the operating system installation (**this method may be more difficult**).

1. That is, during the USB flash drive installation, the power is turned off after the  first reboot of ghost, and the upper driver is not loaded at this time.
2. Then change the new SSD from the PC to the laptop.
3. Then continue to install the operating system on the laptop.
4. We need to set the laptop to boot from the new SSD.
5. View if we can boot from the new SSD successfully.

Hope it helps.